# variable not defined and function doesn't work

Tags: python

Before asking my question, I'll explain what this short piece of code exactly does: first you get a menu where you can make a choice, if you choose 1, it should ask for the watch time (W) views (V) then for the duration of the video (h),(m) and (s). But now when you choose 1 it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:/Users/Arcky/Desktop/youtube-avarage-watch-time-v2 help.py", line 72, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "C:/Users/Arcky/Desktop/youtube-avarage-watch-time-v2 help.py", line 65, in main  
    getchoice(Choice)  
NameError: name 'Choice' is not defined
```

so far I can see is Choice defined in the function called choice()

maybe I should use a different name?

If you can help to fix this and let it work, I would be really grateful

here's the full code

```
   def menu():
    print('make your choice')
    print('1. calculate Av. view duration')
    print('2. end this shit')

   def choice():
    Choice = 0
    Choice = (int(input('make a choice... ')))
    while Choice <= 0 or Choice >= 3:
        print('Error!')
        Choice = (int(input('make a choice... ')))
    return Choice

def getchoice(Choice):
    if Choice == 1:
        print(Choice)
        getwatchtimeandviews()

def getwatchtimeandviews():                            
    W =int(input("Enter Watch Time: "))
    V =int(input("Enter Views: "))
    return W, V

def gettimeofvideo():
    h =int(input("Enter hours:"))
    m =int(input("Enter minutes:"))
    if m >=60:
        m = m-60
        h = h + 1
    s =int(input("Enter seconds:"))
    if s >=60:
        s = s-60
        m = m + 1
        if m >=60:
            m = m-60
            h = h + 1
    return h, m, s

def calculateviewduration(W,V,h,m,s):                           
    A = W / V
    As = A*60
    T = (h*3600) + (m*60) + s
    P = (As/T)*100
    Am = 0
    return 

def checkinput(As, P, Am):
    if As <= 59:
        print('Av. view duration:',round(As),'sec','(',round(P,2),'%)')
        while As > 59:
            Am = Am + 1
            As = As - 60  
        print('Av. view duration:',round(Am),'min', round(As),'sec','(',round(P,2),'%)')
        if P > 100:
            print('error! value cannot be higher then 100%!')

def stop():
    print()

def main():
    menu()
    choice()
    getchoice(Choice)
    print ("Enter duration of video:")
    gettimeofvideo()
    calculateviewduration(W,V,h,m,s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ``Choice`` is only known in the scope of the function that defines it.

Comment: Yes, the variables are local.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `getchoice(Choice)`? As the error says `Choice` isn't defined.

Comment: That's because there is no variable `Choice` in the `main()` function. Assign to one, perhaps from the return value of the `choice()` function. Names in other functions are just local to that function: `Choice = choice()`.

Comment: You probably meant `getchoice(choice())`

Comment: how do i fix it then? I have no idea :(

Comment: The function `choice` returns the variable `Choice`, you need to assign it somewhere. Have you fully understood how function return value works?

Comment: read Python documentation and read through some tutorials. Learn about return values and scopes. Even if you get the ``Choice`` thing worked out, you'll have a bigger issue on this line: ``calculateviewduration(W,V,h,m,s)`` - and believe me, you don't want to make all your variables global.

Comment: Or `Choice = choice()`?

Comment: Actually the 2 existing answers are all bad design.

Answer (score 0):

You should to learn scope of variable.
For example, you defined a choice function, and defined a Choice variable in the choice function, then the Choice variable will effect only in the choice function.
If you want to let some variables effect global, you can define the variable out of funtions, or add global keyword when you define(like global Choice)

Answer (score -1):

The `Choice` variable you declared is limited to `choice` function only. If you want to use it globally make it `global` or define at the top most indentation level

Comment: But... don't. That would be worse.